Issue in simulation files
I have this issue in my project whenever i simulate any circuit, i did ensure that i defined the parameters well and didn't work
Im facing a mismatch in transistor currents as seen in schematic the emitter current is constant at 5pA no matter what biasing current is (Ic)
Would this issues affect the simulation for any amplifier or any circuit i design


"Is all of this because of this issue and how can i solve it": (1) no idea; and, (2) no idea. You may need to clarify your question better.

I don't know what simulator you are using, but I suspect the problem is the placement of the measurement probe being right at the ground symbol. Try measuring right on the transistor pin, or lengthen the wire between the emitter and ground a bit. You might also try putting a very low value resistor (something like 1 µΩ) from the emitter to ground and measuring the current through that.
Also, having no resistances in the circuit may be causing problems. You could try adding resistors to the collector and base circuits. Maybe try simulating a common emitter amplifier with voltage divider bias and emitter degeneration and see if that gives expected results.

I'm using altium's mixed simulation and the probe is automatically placed by software whenever i do operating point analysis and chose the current to display on schematic any ideas ?

@Alghaith See the update to my answer.

@Alghaith Is Altium the right software to use for designing ICs? Try what I said, simulate a discrete amplifier and see if the results are okay. I don't see why the circuit you posted would have the emitter current wrong, I don't have Altium but if I put the same circuit into LTspice it works, so I'm thinking it may be a software problem.

You're right thank you so much altium is not suitable for such complex designs (ICs of transistor level) so it has a faulty simulation when it's only transistors without resistors
